# The sum of all combinations greater than $x$

Tags: probability, combinations

Suppose I choose $3$ integers at random from $\{1,…, 100\}$.  What is the chance that the sum of those integers exceeds  some number $x$?

Is there a nice formula for the sum of all the combinations that equal or exceed a value?

Comment: Choose *with* or *without* replacement?

Comment: without replacement.

Comment: What you say you know, is wrong, since probabilities don't exceed 1, while binomial coefficients do.

Comment: Also, I think you'll find that the formula ${n-1\choose r-1}$ that you have given works for sampling with, not without, replacement. E.g., take $n=4$, $r=3$, so you want three numbers adding up to 4 (if I understand your notation). That can't be done at all without replacement, but it can be done ${3\choose2}=3$ ways with replacement.

Comment: Have you thought about my comments, michael?

Comment: Yes - the formula gives the total outcomes that equal the event. You take that over the complete set of combinations to get the probability. You are tight about it working on replacement.Nevertheless, it doesn't bring me closer to a solution to the problem.

Comment: @michaeljoseph if you choose to do it with replacement, it can be easier with stars and bars theorem, and would have a nice closed form

Comment: That would be good. But I am dealing with a bargaining model in economics about concessions. The idea is that you are choosing concessions to make from scarce resources and you want to know if they will satisfy your rival. As a result, replacement is not possible.

Comment: So, you agree that what you have written about probability is incorrect, and you agree that the formula you give does not apply in the case that interests you. So, why haven't you edited the body of the question to remove the false and irrelevant parts?

Comment: It has a smelling to be of nice closed form, and it is not far from my eye

Comment: I'd love some insight on how to start with it. Do you have a clue to a theorem I could use?

Answer (score 0):

- The sum of all possible selections of 3 distintct numbers is:

$S=\binom{100}3$

- For any number $x$,the collection of all samples of three elements where the sum exceeds $x$ is counted to:

$S_1$=
$\{(1,2,x-3),(1,2,x-3+1)....,(1,2,100)$

$(1,3,x-4)....$

$(1,2+y_1,x-3-y_1)...\}$

= 
$100-x+3+1+100-x+4+1+...100-x+3+y_1+1$=$\frac{(y_1+1)(100-x+4+100-x+4+y_1)}{2}$

$+\{(2,3,x-5),(2,3,x-5+1)....,(2,3,100)$

$(2,4,x-6)....\}=$

$\frac{(y_2+1)(100-x+6+100-x+6+y_2)}{2}+.... + \{(a,a+1,a+2(+1,+2))+....\}$

where: $3a+3(+1,+2)=x$,$a=\lfloor \frac{x-3}{3}\rfloor$

$=\frac{(y_a+1)(100-a-2-xmod3+1+100-a-xmod3-2+y_a+1)}{2}$

Since $x-(i+i+1)-y>i+1+y$,$y<\frac{x-2-3i}{2}=\lfloor \frac{x-3-3i}{2} \rfloor$

$y_a=(xmod3==2)$

---

- Calculating probability:

$P=\frac{\sum_i S_i}{S}=\frac{\frac{(y_1+1)(100-x+4+100-x+4+y_1)}{2}+\frac{(y_2+1)(100-x+6+100-x+6+y_2)}{2}+...\frac{(y_a+1)(100-a-2-xmod3+1+100-a-xmod3-2+y_a)}{2}}{\binom{100}3}$

$=\frac{{(\lfloor \frac{x-6}{2} \rfloor+1)(208-2x+\lfloor \frac{x-6}{2} \rfloor)}+{(\lfloor \frac{x-9}{2} \rfloor+1)(208+2*2-2x+\lfloor \frac{x-9}{2} \rfloor)}+...{(y_a+1)(198-2a-2xmod3+y_a)}}{2\binom{100}3}$

Simplification in progress ..

Comment: This is a really neat approach - thanks! Look forward to the simplification...